# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Unable to read Parquet file with Dask

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask, parquet

Unable to read the parquet file as a dask dataframe. I am able to read with pandas. Please suggest!
I couldn't figure out what I am missing out!
dask version == 1.0.0, pyarrow version == 0.13.0, pandas version ==0.23.4

Sample of Paruet File

```
UniqueReference     DateTime            Consumption
0   ABCD        2018-08-01 00:00:00       9
1   EFGH        2018-08-01 01:00:00       0
2   IJKL        2018-08-01 02:00:00       0
3   MNOP        2018-08-01 03:00:00       0
```

```
import pyarrow
import dask.dataframe as dd

data = dd.read_parquet('myfile.parquet', engine = 'pyarrow')
```

error traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-068eb0627791> in <module>
----> 1 data = dd.read_parquet('myfile.parquet', engine = 'pyarrow').compute()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py in read_parquet(path, columns, filters, categories, index, storage_options, engine, infer_divisions)
   1152 
   1153     return read(fs, fs_token, paths, columns=columns, filters=filters,
-> 1154                 categories=categories, index=index, infer_divisions=infer_divisions)
   1155 
   1156 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py in _read_pyarrow(fs, fs_token, paths, columns, filters, categories, index, infer_divisions)
    685         pandas_metadata = json.loads(schema.metadata[b'pandas'].decode('utf8'))
    686         index_names, column_names, storage_name_mapping, column_index_names = (
--> 687             _parse_pandas_metadata(pandas_metadata)
    688         )
    689     else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\parquet.py in _parse_pandas_metadata(pandas_metadata)
     89         # index name
     90         index_names = list(index_storage_names)  # make a copy
---> 91         index_storage_names2 = set(index_storage_names)
     92         column_names = [name for (storage_name, name)
     93                         in pairs if name not in index_storage_names2]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: What is `dask` and `pyarrow` version?. If they are not latest please upgrade

Comment: dask version == 1.0.0, pyarrow version == 0.13.0, pandas version ==0.23.4

Comment: Can you post a sample of your `parquet` file. Type of columns you have. Looks like an issue with that.

Comment: try `pip install dask --upgrade`. The reason I am asking you to upgrade is current version of dask requires `pyarrow >0,14.0`

Comment: yes i see. i'm doing it.

Comment: It's done thanks!!!

Comment: It works with pyarrow == '0.15.1', pandas == '0.25.1', dask == '2.24.0'

Comment: You may wish to remove this question, or answer your own question giving the versions that are working.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this was with a very old version of Dask from several years ago.  With a modern version this is fine.